# anything like filehamster (revision system) but opensource?

Tags: svn

I know subversion but sometimes I want something simpler like plain old files with just file stamping automatically. 
http://www.filehamster.com/ does this, but I'd prefer something opensource. Anyone knows anything like this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try AutoVer
It's (probably abandoned) freeware and works perfectly for me. I have it set to backup files every time I hit save with minimum 1minute intervals. You can then traverse the files through it's viewer. Can back up to ftp and even has a post-backup command so you could integrate with command line tools like diff.
I also found a launchpad page for [Eloi](https://launchpad.net/eloi) which aims to do something similar by the look of it but still in development.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a list that Susan Bugher created at [Adras / FileHamster alternatives](http://www.adras.com/FileHamster-alternative.t57488-81.html):

Program: KnowledgeTree
Author: Daniel Chalef
Windows NT; 2000; XP
Ware: (Freeware) (open source: GNU GPL)
http://sourceforge.net/projects/kt-dms/

Program: Paper Harbour
Company: Supporting Technologies Nordic
Author: Stephen Dougall
Ware: (Liteware) (free) (open source: GNU LGPL)
http://sourceforge.net/projects/paperharbour/
http://www.supportingtechnologies.com/

Program: DocShield
Company: PanIO Systems
Ware: (Freeware) (free for personal use)
http://www.docshield.com/

Program: Perforce
Company: Perforce Software
Ware: (Liteware) (free)
http://www.perforce.com/

Program: TortoiseCVS
Author: - project team
Ware: (Freeware) (open source: GNU GPL) 
http://www.tortoisecvs.org/

Program: TortoiseSVN
Author: Tim Kemp and Stefan Kueng
Windows 98; NT4; ME; 2000; XP
Ware: (Donationware) (free) (open source: GNU GPL)
http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/

Program: VersionBackup
Company: Schr�der-Bergen Anwendungen (Sb-aw)
Ware: was (Liteware) (free for personal use) LFW (v 4.1.7.0)
http://www.majorgeeks.com/VersionBackup_d4531.html

Comment: only http://www.majorgeeks.com/VersionBackup_d4531.html suits my definition but seems good EXCEPT IT ISN'T FREE :) so there doesn't seem to be any indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the software I wrote called [FolderTrack](http://www.foldertrack.com). It is a [automatic personal version control system](http://www.foldertrack.com). And the UI is open source. Visitors here can have a free license using discount code BOS